# Can I retrieve sound from laptop speakers that has been cancelled unintentionally while recording from a microphone?

Tags: microphone, audio-recording, recording

Is it possible to retrieve any sound from laptop speakers which has been cancelled unintentionally while recording from a microphone in Windows 7? I left the option to remove speakers' "background noise" checked by mistake. It seems to me that it is not possible but I would like to have a second opinion. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The summing/cancellation/noise reduction was done before the source went to 'tape'. The is no 'pre-cleaning' or diff file to go back to. Most 'smart' or AI processes are designed to remove noise not add, so there is no specialist suite of tools to aid you in reversing this process.

There is the vague hope that there may be some small remnant of this signal which may be boosted after the fact, as a separate file. Some noise-reduction software will let you flip to hear what is being removed, as opposed to the result of removal. There may be some small mileage in taking this & seeing what you can gain from it.

Comment: There are tiny remnants of the original sound removed but most of it sounds like someone is playing an annoying flute. Can you elaborate on how to try to get something from this? I just tried to use a very high level of amplification to be able to hear something. My knowledge is very limited on this.

Comment: It's going to be tough. You're going to have to start with something like Izotope RX [there's a free trial] & go through each of the 'restoration' plugins, noise removers, vocal 'rescuers' & see which has an 'inverse' button, because you're trying to rescue what these plugins are all designed to throw away. It's not like you're starting with a bathtub full of floating toy ducks, trying to fish out the ducks; you're trying to analyse the bathwater… after the bath has been emptied.